# References not found using Visual Studio 2019 inside Parallels/Windows10 on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-2019, parallels

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 through Parallels on a Mac and my solution is not finding any references.  I can browse to the location of the references on the Windows' C drive so I know they're there.  But in the properties window of the project in VS, they all show as *"The system cannot find the reference specified"*

What's really weird is I can remove the reference, click "Add", browse to the DLL, select it, add it back to the project successfully, but it still shows as "The system cannot find the reference specified".

I tried the "update Nuget" tool which also just sort of hangs and doesn't do anything.

This has to be some sort of config issue with Parallels, but I'm not finding much info on how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I manually copied the "packages" folder from the same solution on a real Windows10 machine into the "packages" folder on the Parallels/Windows10 and now everything seems to work.
What I don't get is that some of the references that were not being found are not even in that "packages" folder (!)
Yet doing that made VS see all the missing refs.